# c# serialized JSON date to ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, json, serialization

I have a C# application that serializes its DTOs to JSON and sends them accros the wire to be processed by Ruby. Now the format of the serialized date is like so:

```
/Date(1250170550493+0100)/
```

When this hits the Ruby app I need to cast this string representation back to a date/datetime/time (whatever it is in Ruby). Any ideas how I would go about this?

Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse out the milliseconds since the epoch, something like:

```
def parse_date(datestring)
  seconds_since_epoch = datestring.scan(/[0-9]+/)[0].to_i / 1000.0
  return Time.at(seconds_since_epoch)
end

parse_date('/Date(1250170550493+0100)/')
```

You'd still need to handle the timezone info (the `+0100` part), so this is a starting point.

Comment: `parse_date('/Date(1250170550493+0100)/')` returns `41586-04-30 15:21:33 +0200`

Comment: @narzero you're right, in this case it's milliseconds since the epoch, not seconds since the epoch. Fixing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Time.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) to parse this to a `Time` object with the correct time zone:

```
Time.strptime(string, "/Date(%Q%z)/")
```

For example:

```
string = "/Date(1250170550493+0100)/"
Time.strptime(string, "/Date(%Q%z)/")
#=> 2009-08-13 14:35:50 +0100
```

Comment: This is, by far, the most elegant solution. What is strange is that `%Q` is not documented even for the latest Ruby version: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime

Comment: Yeah that's true. Internally it uses `Date.strptime` whose documentation states that the format is the same as for `Date.strftime`. There, it is documented as `%Q - Number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) to serialize your DTOs instead of the built in .NET JSON serializer. It gives you flexibility over how to serializing dates (i.e. as a constructor, ISO format, etc).

Comment: +1, great option if your requirements allow you to change the date serialization format to something Ruby likes better

Comment: BTW - we use Json.NET all the time, great library. Thanks James!

Answer (score 2):

.NET serializes in milliseconds from the epoch, so you need to divide the part before the timezone by 1000. Other wise your dates will be thousands of year off