# How to format a date to JSON in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, date-formatting

I need to produce a date in Rails which looks like this:

/Date(1294268400000)/

I have tried various combinations of DateTime, to_i, to_json but never managed to get the `/Date()/` thing.

Do I have to simply get my date in ms and then wrap the `/Date(`and `)/` manually, or is there a built in method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about (ruby 1.9.x)?:

```
Time.now.strftime("/Date(%s%L)/")
=> "/Date(1335280866211)/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
new Date(posixMillisecondsHere)
```

first.  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) says that calling the `Date` function outside of the constructor context (i.e., without the `new`) will always return a string containing a formatted date rather than a `Date` object.

Strictly speaking, when you do that, you are writing JavaScript and not JSON.  JSON cannot contain Date objects.

[RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says

> 2.1.  Values
>
> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
>     the following three literal names:
>
> ```
>  false null true
> ```

If you want to put a Date into what is strictly considered JSON and then get it back out, you must choose some way of using the JSON primitives (to wit, objects, arrays, numbers, strings, etc.) to encode a Date.

If you want to get a Date back out of JSON, whatever parses your JSON must understand the convention that you used to encode the Date.

Hope these are credible and/or official enough to help.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

in your config/en.yml file:

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      json: "/Date(%s%L)/"
```

and than in the view:

```
<%= l(Time.now, :format => :json) %>
```

Please note that you would need access to the helpers in the method that renders json. So it won't work if you are using ActiveRecord#to_json method for generating jsons.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question:

[c# serialized JSON date to ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272195/c-sharp-serialized-json-date-to-ruby)

... simple answer seems to be to create a parse_date method.

Comment: Thanks (I've seen this one), but I'm not trying to read or parse this format, but rather to produce it. So from Date.new(2012,1,1), how do I get the representation in the format given in my question?

Answer (score 0):

It's the UNIX Epoch (seconds since 1970-01-01) right? What about using [DateTime#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) method?

```
# Taken from the Ruby documentation
seconds_since_1970 = your_date.strftime("%s")
```

**UPDATE**: OK, it's milliseconds, according to the documentation you can use `your_date.strftime("%Q")` to get the ms (but I've not tried yet).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I had figured out the milliseconds thing. My question is about the `/Date(` and `)/`thing. I don't know if this is something standard or if I have to add it manually.